# c#: adding new item to comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want list of clients with their ip address to be added to comboBox in winforms but the list doesn't appear in comboBox.

Here is my code for server

```
// this my list of sockets for each client connected to server
list<Socket> astr = new list<socket>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addfg();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

public void addfg() 
{
  foreach (Socket s in astr) 
  {
    string str = string.Format("client : " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new object[] {str})
  }
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Items[0]);
 }
```

But I am getting error "ArgumentException was unhandled" or in detail "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set".

Comment: 'as' is a C# keyword, just saying

Comment: I am getting exception at comboBox1.Items.Add() line.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed 'as' keyword.

Comment: You should show the code assigning your `comboBox1.DataSource` so that people here can help you, once assigning the `comboBox1.DataSource` to something not-null, you can just use `comboBox1.Items` to read only, can't modify that collection any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
foreach (Socket s in astr) 
{
  string str = string.Format("client : " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

In your version, it looks like you are trying to add an array, but the `Items.Add()` method only adds a single item.  To add multiple items, you would use `AddRange()`, but that doesn't look like the case with your code.

Be careful with this code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Items[0]);
}
```

You should check to see if something is selected:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.SelectedIndex > -1) {
   MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Items[0]);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, but your "be careful" at the end doesn't really make any difference: the messagebox is showing the first item in the list, so whether there's a selection or not doesn't matter. It might be worth checking whether there's something in the list to display, but I'd imagine it's hard to change the selected index if there's not... :-)

Comment: I am still getting error "argumentexception was unhandled" at the same comboBox1.Items.Add() line.

Comment: @user2673943 You can't get that error by adding a string to the Items collection of a combobox, so it's something else.

Comment: @user2673943 If you are using a DataSource on the combobox, then you add items to the DataSource, not the Items collection.

Comment: Thanks LarsTech I was making mistake by setting the DataSource property from the form designer

Answer (score 1):

The [Items.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx) method takes one object as a parameter. You are trying to add an array of objects. Change it like:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(str);
```

**EDIT** : As you have ( probably in the form designer ) set the DataSource property you need to remove this binding.

Comment: I am still getting error "argumentexception was unhandled" at the same comboBox1.Items.Add() line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Items[0]);
```

You might want to use

```
MessageBox.Show(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

In this case the messagebox will display the selected item.

And instead of

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new object[] {str})
```

You can either choose to do:

```
    comboBox1.Items.Add(str);
```

In wich case the string object is added or:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new {Name = str})
```

Right now you are creating a new array  of type object, and you are adding str to it like it should be a property. Also, there is no need to use  an Object[]. What I did is when adding an object I create an anonymous type with a property called Name which will hold the value of Str.

Answer (score 0):

I think this causes your problem:

```
string str = string.Format("client : " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
```

Try using:

```
string str = string.Format("client : " + ((IPEndPoint)s.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
```

Checkout this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx

Also you should add items to combobox as string not as an object array. On index changed event, you should pass string to MessageBox.Show instead of an object.

I'm curious, did you manage to build your example?

Comment: I had tried in this way also but I am getting same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 combobox1.Items.Add("item1");
 combobox1.Items.Add("item2");
```

try this it will work